# Who is Sammy the Snake's mother?

Tags: nate-the-snake

In the short story "Nate the Snake" (http://natethesnake.com/), we are introduced to a snake named Nate who appears to be magical and one-of-a-kind (I won't give away any spoilers). Then, about 3/4 of the way through the story, Nate introduces his son Sammy without any explanation of where he came from.

I'm wondering where Sammy actually came from. Was he born a natural birth? If so, is his mother a regular snake or magical like Nate?  Or, was Sammy magically created by Nate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the whole thing is meant as one long [shaggy dog story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story), the author probably didn't do a lot of world-building beyond what's mentioned in the text. But the story does indicate that Nate had to find a mate to have Sammy, so magical creation is out (and we can speculate it was probably a regular lady-snake, since magical talking snakes are hard to find):

> Nate watched Sammy disappear and then looked back at Jack. "Jack, this
>   is my first son. My first offspring through all the years. You don't
>   even want to know what it took for me to find a mate." Nate grinned to
>   himself. "But anyway, I had a son for a reason. I'm tired. I'm ready
>   for it to be over. I needed a replacement."

Earlier, Nate had also mentioned being left at the stone by another intelligent snake he thought was his father, so maybe this was a job that had been passed down from father-snake to son-snake since time immemorial (Nate claimed the stone was at the location of the original Garden of Eden):

> "Well, umm, how did you get here then? And why is that white pole
>   stuck out of the stone there?" asked Jack.
>
> "Dad left me here. Or, I assume it was my dad. It was another snake -
>   much bigger than I was back then. I remember talking to him, but I
>   don't remember if it was in a language, or just kind of understanding
>   what he wanted. But one day, he brought me to this stone, told me
>   about it, and asked me to do something for him. I talked it over with
>   him for a while, then agreed. I've been here ever since.

So if God or aliens or whoever created the original talking snake, perhaps they also endowed the snake and its descendants with the ability to have a new talking snake as an offspring, so if they were tired of life and ready to die (Nate indicated he was 'ready for it to be over' in the first quote), there would be someone to pass the position to, which was obviously a *very important one* for the reasons revealed in the story.